# Finding an equation for the tangentline of a intersection curve of two solids $x^2+y^2+z^2=8$ and $z^2=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

Two solids, $x^2+y^2+z^2=8$ and $z^2=x^2+y^2$ go through the point $P$: $(2,0,2)$.

My task is to determine an equation for the tangentline to the intersection curve of the two solids at the point $P$.

My first thought was that the intersection curve must be perpendicular to the two solids, and then somehow figuring out the derivative of the curve in some way. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: Can you find an equation that describes the curves of intersection? (Hint: Eliminate a variable)

Comment: I calculate the intersection curve to be $2x^2+2y^2=8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Find the normal vectors to both surfaces at the point $P$. Then the tangent vector is just the cross product of those two vectors. Then you should be able to find the tangent line.

Comment: I calculated the normal vectors of the tangent planes of the two surfaces at the point $P$. These are $(4,0,4)$ and $(4,0,-4)$, if lets say my result of the cross product is ment to be $(a,b,c)$ then I get $-32b=0$, so $b=0$, but how do I determine $a$ and $c$?

Comment: @osk I haven't checked whether they are indeed the normal vectors, but you seem to calculate the dot product, not the cross product. Find the cross product, you should get a vectors as a result, not a number.

Comment: @osk Don't set the cross product to 0. Wolfram Alpha gives us that the cross product is $(0,32,0)$. This is the direction vector of the tangent line.

Comment: Oh you are right, I made a mistake by setting it to 0, that seems correct. So that should give me the tangent $(x,y,z)=(2,0,2)+t(0,-32,0)$. However now when I looked at the correct answer I'm kind of lost, it says that the equation of the tangent line is $x=2, y=s, z=2$ where $s$ is a parameter.

Comment: @osk Your answer is right. Note that you get $(x,y,z) = (2,-32t,2)$. This is exactly the same, as first the author normalized the vector. To get the same answer you can introduce the substitution $-32t = s$

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, I'll just ignore the "correct" answer in my material. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @osk You can read my edited comment to see why the answers coincide.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again!